# ASP.Net Core Email Breaks Suddenly Citing SSL Time Mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl

After noticing that nobody has signed up for a site of mine for a week I tried signing up myself only to be greeted with an error message. Then I tried signing up the site by running it in debug mode using Visual Studio 2022, but couldn't sign up that way due to the following:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The server certificate has the following errors:
• A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.
MySite.Services.EmailSender.SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message) in EmailSender.cs, line 51

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection. The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons: • The server certificate has the following errors: • A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.
PostAlmostAnything.SiteServices.EmailSender.SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message) in EmailSender.cs
+
            throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
LoginModel.OnPostSendVerificationEmailAsync() in Login.cshtml.cs
+
        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(userEmail, "Confirm your email", "Please confirm your account by <a href='" + HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl) + "'>clicking here</a>.");
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Is the certificate expired or not?

Comment: I did recently purchase a new SSL certificate for that site which unlike the last one is not a wildcard certificate. I don't know if that would do it or not. I also don't host the email on the same server. I have a second server I host Wordpress sites on which is also the email server for this site as well as others. I find it much easier to use cPanel for email. I doubt the email server is the issue since other sites are setup the same way and they still send mail fine.

Comment: This is for serverfault, not for S.O. Pretty obvious this is a SSL issue.

Comment: If it is an SSL issue then why don't any of the other sites have the same problem? I checked in IIS and verified the certificate being used for the bindings is the current one NOT the expired one.

Comment: I think this issue must be related to something in .Net 5 that doesn't exist in sites built using the old ASP.Net framework since that seems to be the only difference at the moment.

Comment: Since this problem seems to make all form based emails fail I have concluded that this problem began between Monday and today.

Comment: I have made no changes capable of explaining this on my end. I have not accessed the sever via RD until today and I have not uploaded anything to it for some time.

Comment: It seems the AutoSSL on the email server started issuing expired certificates. Is there any way to tell .Net Core to send the message anyway?